# Can you prepend a string to all values in mapped response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, concatenation

I get an array of objects from an api call that includes a partial url for some images, what I want to do is prepend a base uri to each of these values so I can then render the images in my view.

How can I achieve this?

My current response is:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {size: "100x100", url: "100x100/kidscorner.svg"}
1: {size: "100x100_black", url: "100x100_black/kidscorner.svg"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have tried, string concat, .map. concat and god knows what else. I am sure it's possible and should be easy but cant quite achieve it.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: using `Array.forEach` should do the trick: `arr.forEach(r=> { r.url = baseURL + r.url })`

Comment: Sure. `images = images.map(image => ({ ...image, url: some_prefix + image.url }));`

Comment: @Eldar this solution worked for me. Should have out this as an answer not comment. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, no further effort needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and template string to simplify.

```js
const data = [
  { size: "100x100", url: "100x100/kidscorner.svg" },
  { size: "100x100_black", url: "100x100_black/kidscorner.svg" }
];

const res = data.map(({ size, url }) => ({ size, url: `example.com/${url}` }));

console.log(res);
```